# Hold and Release in Xcode (Sound)?

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, touch

So, I just basically want to use AVFoundation Kit for playing my sound. I have the play method set, but I want to be able to hold down the button and play the sound that way rather than tapping it first. Once I release the button, I want the sound to stop. Simple: Hold down to play sound and then release your finger to stop the sound like a piano. Help please! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right click on the button in IB you should be able to link the

Touch down

and

Touch Cancelled

button links so that it they both call the same method or they each call a different method one to stop the sound and one to start it.

you might also want to check out this

[forum](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/36530-playing-audio-when-app-launches.html)

hope this helps

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. All I want to be able to do is hold the button to play sound, and release the button to stop the sound. HOW?

Comment: I don't quite understand why my answer isn't helpful? Pushing the button calls a method and starts a sound. And releasing it calls a method stopping the sound